# Simple locking with buffered channels spinning

Tags: go

The following is loosely based on Go in Practice (page 81):

```
$ cat simple_locking_with_buffered_channels.go 
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main(){
    reap := 0; sow := 0
    lock := make(chan bool,4100)
    for i:=0; i<4001; i++{
        go worker(i, lock, &reap)
        sow += 1
    }
    for reap != sow {
        fmt.Println("*yawn*")
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    close(lock)
}


func worker(i int, lock chan bool, reap *int){
    fmt.Printf("%d wants the lock\n", i)
    lock <-true // we acquire the lock thusly.
    fmt.Printf("%d has the lock\n", i)
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) 
    fmt.Printf("%d is releasing the lock\n", i)
    *reap += 1
    <-lock // release
}
```

When I run it, most of the time it finishes, but occasionally I see that it spins on yawn - perpetually so, until it is killed. Yes, I can add a timeout logic, but I want to know why is this happening.

```
$ ps -p `pgrep  simple_locking` -o lstart,etime
                 STARTED     ELAPSED
Sun Jul  8 11:34:59 2018       02:41
$ ps -p `pgrep  simple_locking` -o lstart,etime
                 STARTED     ELAPSED
Sun Jul  8 11:34:59 2018       03:24
```

It is supposed to work, then why is the odd behavior happening. in those cases, why is my reap != sow ?

```
~/golearn $ go version
go version go1.10.3 linux/amd64
```

I am running this on an busy old-ish linux laptop, I am baffled why does it spin intermittently? Thanks in advance!

https://play.golang.org/p/BJwAmRf1OXB

**update : 1**

I changed the code to use mutex (or so I think..) as:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

var mutex sync.Mutex

func main(){
    reap := 0; sow := 0
    lock := make(chan bool,400)
    for i:=0; i<389; i++{
        go worker(i, lock, &reap)
        sow += 1
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    for reap != sow {
        fmt.Println("*yawn*")
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    close(lock)
}


func worker(i int, lock chan bool, reap *int){
    fmt.Printf("%d wants the lock\n", i)
    lock <-true // we acquire the lock thusly.
    fmt.Printf("%d has the lock\n", i)
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) 
    fmt.Printf("%d is releasing the lock\n", i)
    mutex.Lock()
    *reap += 1
    mutex.Unlock()
    <-lock // release
}
```

Is this the right way, since `go run --race` still says `WARNING: DATA RACE` ?

***update 3: ***

After trying go's atomic counters, which require delays between increments, I ended up using mutex. What I learned was : even reading (as opposed to writing) can make it complain of race conditions. So here, I wrapped my call in a function call which uses mutex to read, and it clears the --race tests:

```
$ cat improv.go
package main

import(
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "sync"
)

var mutex sync.Mutex

func main(){
        sow := 0
        reap := 0

        lock := make(chan bool,40)
        for i:=0; i<38; i++{
                go worker(i, lock, &reap)
                sow += 1
        }
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)


        //for  get_counter(&reap) != get_counter(&sow) {
        for  get_counter(&reap) != sow {
                fmt.Println("*yawn*")
                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        }
}

func worker(i int, lock chan bool, reap *int){
        fmt.Printf("%d wants the lock\n", i)
        lock <-true // we acquire the lock thusly.
        fmt.Printf("%d has the lock\n", i)
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Printf("%d is releasing the lock\n", i)
        mutex.Lock()
        defer mutex.Unlock()
        *reap += 1
        <-lock // release
}

func get_counter(counter *int) int {
        mutex.Lock()
        defer mutex.Unlock()
        return *counter
}

 $ go run --race improv.go >/dev/null
```

Comment: I don't see how this would lock anything.

Comment: are you referring to the buffer count (4100) being larger than the no. of goroutines spawned (4000)?

Comment: variable reap doesn't guarded anyhow for concurrent usage. Code looks unsafe. Simultaneous use of *reap by two or more goroutines can lead to unpredictable state.

Comment: @struggling_learner: "Is this the right way?" No. When you have a data race your results are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the tutelage, I learned that merely reading a variable that's being written elsewhere into, can make `--race` complain of `WARNING: DATA RACE`.  So here, I wrapped my call in a function call which uses mutex to read, and it clears the `--race` test.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var mutex sync.Mutex

func main() {
    sow := 0
    reap := 0

    lock := make(chan bool, 40)
    for i := 0; i < 38; i++ {
        go worker(i, lock, &reap)
        sow += 1
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)

    //for  get_counter(&reap) != get_counter(&sow) {
    for get_counter(&reap, &sow) {
        fmt.Println("*yawn*")
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}

func worker(i int, lock chan bool, reap *int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d wants the lock\n", i)
    lock <- true
    fmt.Printf("%d has the lock\n", i)
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("%d is releasing the lock\n", i)
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    *reap += 1
    <-lock
}

func get_counter(reap *int, sow *int) bool {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    return *reap == *sow
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has data races (see [Go Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)). Therefore, your results are undefined.

```
$ go run -race racer.go > /dev/null
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000086010 by goroutine 7:
  main.worker()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/so/racer.go:29 +0x1c9

Previous write at 0x00c000086010 by goroutine 661:
  main.worker()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/so/racer.go:29 +0x1e2

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/so/racer.go:13 +0xb0

Goroutine 661 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/so/racer.go:13 +0xb0
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000086010 by goroutine 688:
  main.worker()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/so/racer.go:29 +0x1c9

Previous write at 0x00c000086010 by goroutine 661:
  main.worker()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/so/racer.go:29 +0x1e2

Goroutine 688 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/so/racer.go:13 +0xb0

Goroutine 661 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/so/racer.go:13 +0xb0
==================
Found 2 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

---

Your code for update-1 has data races. Therefore, your results are undefined.

```
$ go run -race racer.go >/dev/null
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c000088010 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/src/so/racer.go:20 +0x136

Previous write at 0x00c000088010 by goroutine 397:
  main.worker()
      /home/peter/src/so/racer.go:34 +0x1f2

Goroutine 397 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/src/so/racer.go:16 +0xb0
==================
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

Comment: thanks @peterSO, could you please advise on **update : 1**  made to the question

Comment: @struggling_learner:  update-1  has a data race. See my revised answer.

Comment: yep, i noticed that too. How would you refactor that update-1 code to avoid the race condition?

Answer (score 1):

There's no conditional logic present in your code whether to change `*reap` based on the status of `lock`, or whether to wait for the status of `lock` to change before proceeding with the update to `*reap`.  Therefore you're getting multiple goroutines increasing `*reap` with no synchronization between them.

Compare your implementation to the documented behavior of [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex), especially the block and wait behavior:

> Lock locks m. If the lock is already in use, the calling goroutine
>   blocks until the mutex is available.